# Диапазон даты mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
echo " Date 1<input type=\"datetime-local\" name=\"calendar1\">";
echo " Date 2<input type=\"datetime-local\" name=\"calendar2\">";


$date1 = $_POST['calendar1'];
$date2 = $_POST['calendar2'];

$date1___ = str_replace("T"," ",$date1);
$date2___ = str_replace("T"," ",$date2);

$date1__ = $date1___.":00";
$date2__ = $date2___.":00";

$date1_ = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date1__));
$date2_ = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date2__));

$query = "SELECT $comma_separated  FROM first_table where price between $dip1 and $dip2 and count between $dip3 and $dip4 and deliverydate between $date1_  AND $date2_ ORDER BY $radio ASC ";
```

SELECT id,name,sex,goodsname,address FROM first_table where price between 313 and 3131 and count between 31 and 313 and deliverydate between 2018-02-01 00:00:00 AND 2019-01-01 00:03:00 ORDER BY count ASC 
Вот здесь выдает ошибку, что неправильно в запросе
and deliverydate between 2018-02-01 00:00:00 AND 2019-01-01 00:03:00

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с count запрос работает проблема с датой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строки с датами должны быть заключены в апострофы:

```
$query = "
    SELECT $comma_separated  
    FROM first_table 
    where 
        price between $dip1 and $dip2 
        and count between $dip3 and $dip4 
        and deliverydate between '$date1_'  AND '$date2_' 
    ORDER BY $radio ASC 
";
```